# how to join multiple lines in notepad++ with comma as a separator

Tags: python, notepad++

I need to join multiple lines in notepad++ into one single line with comma as a separator

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

the output that I need is as below

```
one,two,three,four,five
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> will join but will add space

Comment: Are you looking to manipulate strings in python or your text editor?

Comment: as @ryugie mentioned, @Pravkulk, could you please specify if you're trying to program in `python` or want to know how to do this in `Notepad++`?

Answer (score 5):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=\S)`
- Replace with: `,`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R     : any kind of linebreak
(?=\S) : Positive lookahead, make sure we have a non space character after, to avoid inserting a comma at the end of the string
```

**Result for given example:**

```
one,two,three,four,five
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the last `,` from the list!

Answer (score 3):

CTRL+ H -> check "regular expression" -> search `\s\r\n` (or `\s+` )-> replace all with `,`.

Similar question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/915965/notepad-merge-all-lines-into-one-and-add-separator).